# How to convert a string c# equation to an answer

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, equation, equation-solving

I am building a WP8 app it is solving numerical analysis problems. For one step i need to parse entered function but I dont have any knowledge about parsing and I tried something else

I have a stackpanel with mathematical components (Sin(x),Cos(x),Tan(x),+,-,*...)

when user click any component

For example  first
 Sin(x)
then + and then Cos(x)

```
string yazılıdenklem =""; int xdegeri=Convert.ToInt32(Xtxt.Text);

private void Sin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        yazılıdenklem=yazılıdenklem+"Math.Sin("+xdegeri.ToString()+")";

    }

 private void artı_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        yazılıdenklem = yazılıdenklem + "+";
    }
 private void Cos_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        yazılıdenklem = yazılıdenklem + "Math.Cos(" + xdegeri.ToString() + ")";
    }
```

End of choosing I having a string equation like : "Math.Sin(3)+Math.Cos(3)" can i transform this equation to any numerical form ? Can I get any result from this string eq. ? Thank you

Comment: Read about [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: @KonradKokosa NCalc library doesn't support win 8 or win 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bcParser.NET is a safe eval() function to evaluate math formulas. bcParser.NET is a Math Parser Library for the .NET Platform. bcParser.NET parses and evaluates mathematical expressions given as strings at runtime.

```
MathParser.SetExpression("sin(3)+cos(3)");
double value = MathParser.getValueAsDouble();
```

Comment: I added bcParser dll and wrote my code like this `MathParser parser = new MathParser();
            parser.SetVariable("sin(3)+cos(3)", 15);
            double result = parser.ValueAsDouble;
            Denklem.Text = result.ToString();` but it is not working it is saying `Additional information: sin(3)+cos(3) is not a valid variable name.`

Comment: It is worked there is just one mistake in code `parser.SetVariable` not working use parser.Expression instead. Thank you @JeevaMahendran

Comment: but bcParser is not free